# Interpreting "takes as input a sorted list of N integers output will be sorted squared integer list"

Tags: algorithm

how would you interpret that sentence in order to start coding. do you take it as the user inputs the number into an array or does it come from a text document for example and just scan it.

I already did it for both but I only have one submission so I have to make it count

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about details specific to an assignment and can only be accurately answered by the asker's professor.

Comment: I say it takes a sorted list `[0, 2, 5, 7, 9]` and returns `[0, 4, 25, 49, 81]`, but must work with negatives too `[-3, 0, 3]` returns `[0, 9 , 9]`

Comment: As others have mentioned, the important aspect is a function which takes a list. How you test this function is probably arbitrary  (e.g. hard-coded examples, file reading, stdin), unless it's supposed to go through some automatic testing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the requirement is very clear - you need to write a function that receives a sorted list of integers, and returns a list of their squares.
E.g., in Java:

```
public List<Integer> squareList (List<Integer list) {
    List<Integer> retVal = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for (int item : list) {
        retVal.add(item * item);
    }
    Collections.sort(retVal);
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Note that he/she was asking about input format, and you did the entire homework.

Comment: But it's an incorrect answer, so that's ok.